# Grails integration test setUp and junit annotation

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have some executeQuery in the code for complex group by/having clause so I need an integration test case to test it. Grails 2.1.1 was used.

However, I found several issues:
1. the setUp method is not called automatically before the test.
2. So I add @Before annotation to the setUp method and it can be called now. But the executeQuery statement can't be used now.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.
```

It seems I can't use any annotation in the integration test. Otherwise it becomes a unit test case? If I don't use any annotation, the test passed.

Here is the code example.

```
class JustTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    void setUp() {
        log.warn "setup"
    }

    void tearDown() {
        log.warn "cleanup"
    }

    void "test something"() {
        // Here is the code to invoke a method with executeQuery
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your test is in the `test\integration` folder?

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure. As it works for the executeQuery without the annotation.

Comment: Are you using the `@TestFor` annotation?

Comment: No. I don't use any annotation to make the test pass.

Comment: I have this problem as well with Grails 2.3.5. Consider the following: <pre><code>class SimpleTests extends GroovyTestCase { def myDomain void setUp() { myDomain = new DomainObject().save() } void testFoo() { assertNotNull(myDomain) } void testBar() { assertNotNull(myDomain) } } </code></pre> Both tests will fail but break at any assert and ask what myDomain is and it won't be null.

Comment: Solved my problem, method chaining doesn't work in this case as save() doesn't return the saved instance. Doesn't seem related to the original problem.